# How to apply animation via anim folder in WallpaperService class

Tags: android, android-animation, live-wallpaper

The beow code in not working in wallpaper service class though it works fine in Activity class.

```
Bitmap image;
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.scale_single);
image.startAnimation(anim);
```

How can I apply animation in wallpaper service class using tween animation.

Comment: i'm not sure if it will work but you can try YourService.this instead of getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 0):

```
image= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
image.startAnimation(animation); r code here
```

Comment: how can i take R.id.image

Comment: are you want start animation on imageview click . right?

Comment: Not on imageview click, but whenever the imageview is drawn on the canvas, then the animation should start.